# grub mkconfig finds Fedora and updates the config file, but Fedora doesn't appear in GRUB after reboot

Tags: boot, multi-boot, fedora, grub, arch-linux

I am a bit new to Linux, so please excuse my lack of knowledge and skill. I basically tried to triple boot Windows, Fedora, and Arch. I have two drives in my computer. One of them has Windows installed on it, and the other one has both Fedora and Arch installed on it.

This is what the partitions look like:

```
nvme1n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0 475.9G  0 part
└─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0   991M  0 part
nvme0n1     259:5    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:6    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:7    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:8    0   100G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p4 259:9    0   200G  0 part /home
├─nvme0n1p5 259:10   0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p6 259:11   0   300G  0 part
```

Arch is in `nvme0n1p6` and Fedora's root partition is in `nvme0n1p3`

Now, I am running into two issues.

This is what my boot menu looks like in UEFI: https://imgur.com/a/S6DsQ1M

Now, if I choose the Fedora one, it displays this GRUB: https://imgur.com/a/SRiFWuq

When I choose Arch, it shows this error: https://imgur.com/a/u1q3JwB

I have tried chrooting into the root partition by using the installation medium and running `mkinitcpio -p linux`. This did not fix it. I can still boot into Arch by choosing GRUB from the UEFI boot menu.

This is what that GRUB looks like: https://imgur.com/a/B1LBu9u

The second problem is this. I tried to add Fedora to this GRUB by logging into Arch, mounting the root partition of Fedora and running grub-mkconfig. Here's what I did: https://imgur.com/a/rtTiUTd

When I reboot, I see the GRUB without Fedora in it. I am not sure what is going on.

If someone can help me, I will be very grateful!